# Canvas performance background

Tags: performance, html, canvas, background

Im using a canvas that updates every milisecond; with an empty background my application has a good performance, after adding a background based on a tiled image, it seems to work about the same...I´m  thinking on adding some new features to my application and was wondering, is it better to use a new static canvas as a background or to use a background based on a tiled image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a test of drawImage performance back in October that tested images versus a canvas: http://jsperf.com/canvas-vs-image

It seems that drawing from an image is faster in firefox and opera, slower in IE9, and about the same in Chrome.

I would think that a tiled image would be better, especially if it were large, but I wouldn't worry much about which one you pick until it is really time to optimize down the road.